# Why does sadness exist as a separate emotion?

Tags: emotion

I tried looking up an answer to this question, but all I got were links to depression hotlines. Gotta love Google :)

Why is sadness as a separate emotion beneficial? Sadness seems mostly to be associated with loss, or a severe change in one's future. Not getting a job, losing a loved one to death or breakup, regret for a decision made or event occurred that can't be undone. It seems in all of these cases that simple pain would suffice just as well, and yet there exists a dedicated emotion for it.

What is the benefit of feeling sadness as a distinct emotion from pain?

Comment: Which model of emotion are you referring to? Could you please link to it/cite it? If you don't have any in mind, maybe instead ask "Is sadness a separate emotion?", and hint at an interest in how emotions are modeled in research.

Comment: Are you looking for an evodevo argument for sadness? Those are probably more interesting than some categorization arg. See e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2267800/ ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_approaches_to_depression

Comment: @Fozz I am! Got an answer in mind?